# Javascript top toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I want to implement a toolbar (probably with javascript) that will be displayed on the top of any site. So, suppose I will enter to google.com, I want on top of the the main page to display my toolbar. Do you have any idea of how this can be implemented to work on any browser ?

I'm a newbie in this domain. Can you give me an example of how this can be done ?

Thanks

Comment: You want the toolbar of your website to be displayed on top of any website the visitor goes to after yours? If so, that's not possible in HTML/Javascript. You'd need to write a browser extension.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right! Sorry for that! :)

Comment: @jValdron No worries, I started typing an answer myself before I realised.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want and I guess this must be implemented differently for each browser. So is any way to do it for all browsers ? For example, can this be done using a proxy and redirecting the page ?

Comment: You could use a proxy yes, but then you would have trouble with secured pages, it would be seen as tampering the pages. Also, this would be more than just JavaScript, it would be more like setting up a proxy server (such as Squid), then configuring it so that it inserts contents to every page response.

Comment: Sounds complicated :) I guess the best solution is to write a plugin for each browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you plan to package this as a browser extension/plugin (eg, for Chrome, Firefox or Safari), you will no doubt run into cross-site scripting security issues if you're trying to run javascript on another domain's page (unless you're planning to have other site owners voluntarily include your script in their pages, too; in this case, ignore this answer).

You could always go old-school and create a top 'frame,' running the third-party content within a bottom frame, but the top navbar would be unable to interact with this content, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without writing a browser plugin. You'll have to make browser-specific plugins for that.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not explicitly necessary to bind a toolbar to the top of the page... just apply some CSS to the wrapper element of your toolbar like so:

```
#toolbar_wrapper {
  position: static;
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; /* assuming your toolbar starts at the left edge of the window */
}
```

However, precisely what you are saying you want to accomplish is to have your own toolbar appear in your browser regardless of what domain you browse to. The correct way is to code it as a browser plug-in/add-on, but you could just load your content into an IFRAME or DIV. Place an "Address" text box into your toolbar where you would enter your URLs, and then use Javascript to load that URL into an IFRAME or DIV. Note that you will never be able to browse using your browser's address bar using this approach, and you will lose a great deal of functionality in the browser and in visited websites. Doing it this way will get you a hobbled illusion of a browser implementation at best.